# Icenium capture sample and PhoneGap 3.4, static page, no feedback

Tags: android, cordova

I am very new to PhoneGap/Cordova, but a full time web developer.

I installed a JDK, Android ADT Bundle, ANT, node.js, etc.  And have successfully launched the PhoneGap "Hello World" application through the command line.  I am using a windows 7 computer, and a Motorola Razr Maxx HD.

The next step, as I see it, is to get some example code up and running so that I can dissect it. I am currently trying to get the following example up and running:

https://github.com/Icenium/sample-capture

I downloaded the repository as a .zip, and then proceeded to delete the contents in my "Hello World" application's "www" folder.  I then placed the example files (sample-capture/sample-capture) within that same folder, rebuilt the project, and pushed it to my device.

Everything APPEARS as it should, but all of the buttons are non-responsive.  This is a verified working project, and I am trying to get the basics of it working so that I can further build off of it.  I have spent a few hours googling and trying a couple of different things, but to no avail.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using Icenium as well?

Comment: Mmm... And therein lies my folly. I take it icenium is not simply a user?

Comment: Correct, Icenium is a service you can use to build hybrid apps and it can work w/ phonegap. I would check out `docs.phonegap.com` and grab their samples. most of them work out of the box and are complete working examples.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for catching my oversight!